# Update data every 60 sec - vanilla js SPA

Tags: javascript

I have this function that renders some html, and I don't know how to call setInterval function here, to call render func after every 60 sec

```
const Home = {

    render: async () => {
        const cryptos = await getAllCryptos();

        const view = `
            <section class="section">
                <table>
                    ${cryptos.data.map(crypto =>
                        `<tr>
                            <td class="name"><a href="/src/#/crypto/${crypto.id}">${crypto.name}</a> </td>
                            <td>${crypto.symbol}</td>
                            <td>${crypto.quote.USD.price}</td>
                            <td>${crypto.quote.USD.percent_change_24h}</td>
                        </tr>`
                        )}
                    </table>
                </section>
        `;
        return view
    }
};

export default Home;
```

I cant really put render function inside `setInterval`, so I am wondering what is the best way to do it?

Comment: It would help if you said **why** you think you can't put `render` in `setInterval`. (I can guess at why, but...)

Comment: Well first you might want to create an instance of Home, and then call `home.render()`.

Comment: Are you sure you’re not using some kind of framework here? Doesn’t look very “vanilla” to me.

Comment: @04FS - It's just an `async` function called `render` using template literals. That's all vanilla. React doesn't have a trademark on the name `render`. :-) (And its `render` isn't `async`.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yeah but if they weren’t using any given framework/library, then I’d rather expect them to know how/where/when to call their own render method …

Comment: @NenadVracar - `setInterval` + async processing = chaotic behavior. :-)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder What would be the problem in this case?

Comment: @NenadVracar - If the asynchronous processing ever takes longer than the interval, the interval timer fires and starts the asynchronous processing a second time, overlapping with the first. The second call can even finish before the first one does, leading to stale results being shown. Not terribly likely in this case with a 60-second timeout (though those sound a lot like "famous last words"), but it's in general an anti-pattern.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Got it, thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed, using `setInterval` would be chaotic given that `render` involves asynchronous processing.

Instead, a chained series of `setTimeout` would probably be best:

```
const RENDER_INTERVAL = 60000; // 60 seconds in milliseconds
function handleRender() {
    Home.render()
        .then(html => {
            // ...use the HTML...
        })
        .catch(error => {
            // ...report the error...
        })
        .finally(scheduleRender);
}
function scheduledRender() {
    setTimeout(handleRender, RENDER_INTERVAL);
}
```

That code assumes you want to continue even if one call to `Home.render` fails.

If you want to use 60 seconds from the *beginning* of the last call to `render` rather than the end (the above is 60 seconds from the end), you'd do a bit more logic:

```
const RENDER_INTERVAL = 60000; // 60 seconds in milliseconds
let lastRenderStart = 0;
function handleRender() {
    lastRenderStart = Date.now();
    Home.render()
        .then(html => {
            // ...use the HTML...
        })
        .catch(error => {
            // ...report the error...
        })
        .finally(scheduleRender);
}
function scheduledRender() {
    setTimeout(handleRender, Math.max(0, RENDER_INTERVAL - (Date.now() - lastRenderStart));
}
handleRender();
```